# How can I download this model from colaboratory

Tags: python, download, google-colaboratory, download-manager

```
model.save("fruits" + ".h5")
print "Model saved"
```

How can I download this model from google colaboratory?

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('fruits.h5')
```